# How to change score for the record

Tags: elasticsearch

1. I'm using elastic search 6.4.0 and want to change the score for a specific record in the index.
2. What the boost will exactly perform When I send the below request. I am seeing score values are changing but the values are not updated in the index its giving me on the query time only. I am bit confused with the boost.

   > GET index/_search
   >       {
   >         "query": {
   >           "multi_match": {
   >             "query": "foo bar",
   >             "fields": ["title^5", "content"]
   >           }
   >         }
   >       }

Answer (score 0):

The score is not saved in the index, it's calculated with each query. Your boost is saying a match of `foo bar` in the title field is 5 times more valuable than a match in the content field. This doesn't get persisted anywhere, it's just reflected in the score of your query results as you saw.